# Check data exist in cache or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In below function I want to cache a data and store into cache memory, from the service I am getting data .

I dont know how to check whether data is exist in cache or not , if suppose data is exist in cache
then I dont want to call webservice just display data which is exist in cache memory.

```
    public string EmployeeNames
    {
        get
        {
            var employeenames = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default["EmployeeNames"];
            
            // getting data from web service one bye one and storing into employeenames
            employeenames = AccountModel.EmployeeNames(EmployeeInfo);
            
            System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default["EmployeeNames"] = employeenames;
            return employeenames.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check it by using `MemoryCache.Contains` which determines whether a cache entry exists in the cache and in case it does, fetch it by using the `Get` method which will return a value whatever you have stored in the cache. if not getting it will return a null value.

```
var cache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache;

if (cache != null && cache.Contains("EmployeeNames"))
{
    var EmployeeNames = cache.Get("EmployeeNames");
}
```

More about `MemoryCache.Contains` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.contains?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: Thanks for response can you please let me know this System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache; dll available in which nuget package I have using System.Runtime.Caching; this one

Comment: It's under the same `System.Runtime.Caching` you are using my friend

Comment: @ Ran Turner                                                                                                              
 using System.Runtime.Caching;
                                                                                                                                 using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache;   // here I am getting error not allowing me set this

Comment: You don't need to use `using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCach`

Comment: Then How can I use this in code its not allowing, if I write in a function as you mentioned , I am getting compile time error like memory cache is not valid in given context.

Comment: Please check out this walkthrough my friend - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/memory-cache-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```cs
var employeenames = MemoryCache.Default.Get("EmployeeNames");
```

If the item is not present in the cache this returns null.

You can use `Contains` to see if an item is present:

```cs
if(MemoryCache.Default.Contains("EmployeeNames"))
```

but as unlikely as it is, there's a possibility that `Contains` will return "true" but the item won't be in the cache a moment later when you retrieve it. So I'd just `Get` it and see if it's null, and only use `Contains` to see if it's present if you don't also want to retrieve it.